# Wrong input value sent to child component

Tags: angular

I have two components "YearComponent" and "StatPeriod" component.
In my YearComponent I call StatPeriod like this :
`<app-save-stat-period [dateBegin]="dateBegin" [dateEnd]="dateEnd" byMonth bestNAverage></app-save-stat-period>`

I have a select input to chose a year :
`<mat-select [(value)]="yearSelected" (selectionChange)="dateChange()" placeholder="Année">`

yearSelected variable is managed this way

```
get dateBegin() {
    return moment()
      .year(this.yearSelected)
      .startOf('year')
      .format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  }

  get dateEnd() {
    return moment()
      .year(this.yearSelected)
      .endOf('year')
      .add(1, 'days')
      .format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  }
```

With the code above you can see that dateBegin() and dateEnd() update when my two-way binding yearSelected changes.

He is the function dateChange() I use :

```
dateChange(): void {
    this.statPeriod.reloadAverageBest(this.dateBegin, this.dateEnd);
  }
```

this.statPeriod is created with this ViewChild :
`@ViewChild(StatPeriodComponent, { static: false }) statPeriod: StatPeriodComponent;`

The method reloadAverageBest() is described below :

```
reloadAverageBest(dateBegin: string, dateEnd: string) {
    this.getStat(dateBegin, dateEnd);
    this.getCalls();
    this.getSaves();
  }
```

The thing I don't understand is when I'm changing the yearSelected from 2020 to 2019 for exemple I have a call made to my api for 2020 and not 2019.
When I'm changing it to 2018 it calls 2019 and then when I go to 2019 or 2020 again it calls 2018.

So it seems that StatPeriodComponent is refreshed with the year selected before and not the year I actually select.

Do you have an idea of what happens here ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it takes time to reflect two way bindings. Means `selectionChange` callback happens before two way biding gets updated.

Can you please try below option?

```
Change your select input
<mat-select [(value)]="yearSelected" (selectionChange)="dateChange($event)" placeholder="Année">
```

Change your `dateChange` function to accept param

```
dateChange({value}): void {
    //here value will point to latest year
    <<use value to convert dateBegin and dateEnd>>
}
```

**Second option**

Why are you calling the child function directly? You are passing `dateBegin` and `dateEnd` to your child component, you can use `onChange` lifecycle event and call API.

Comment: I do not even know why I didn't think to use onChange... Must have been coding for too long now :D
Thank you very much, it's fixed